# Bootstrap check radio button on expand collapse menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to create accordion menu whit radio buttons, when click on menu check the radio buttons, my actual code [is this](http://www.bootply.com/j6XnDwSKym).

I need when open the first menu 'instant delivery' is open and radio button checked, when click on 'delivery time' check your radio button. How  can I do this?

Comment: You need to attach an event listener to that radio button (javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get your last sentence, but i assume you want the radio buttons checked when your accordion divs are clicked. you can use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method to acheive that. so use this jquery script code

```
$("a[href='#collapse1']").click(function()
{
    $('#instant_delivery').prop('checked',true);
});
 $("a[href='#collapse2']").click(function()
{
    $('#optionsRadios1').prop('checked',true);
});
```

heres your [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rWavmg?editors=1010)